# Ruby - in what module is `each` implemented in?

Tags: ruby

I thought it was Enumerable but appears it is not. Is it a native Array method or from some other module? Is there a way to query where it is located?

Comment: `some_object.method(:each).owner`; `some_object.method(:each). source_location`